# Embed HAML variable using Ruby interpolation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but here's a small excerpt from my HAML template:

```
- player = log.player
%tr#player-row-#{player.id}
```

This is giving me the following error:

```
Illegal element: classes and ids must have values.
```

Am I embedding it wrong?

Comment: You can't embed Ruby inside tag declarations, only inside the contents of a tag or its attributes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
- player = log.player
%tr{:id => "player-row-#{player.id}"}
```

Comment: And at that point it makes more sense to only use: `%tr{:id => "player-row-#{log.player.id}"}`

Comment: Better yet, `%tr{id: "player-row-#{log.player.id}"}` :p

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, you can use the slightly more succinct `()` form of attribute specification:

```haml
%tr(id="player-row-#{log.player.id}")
```